# UITableView embedded in view not sizing accordingly

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I am trying to add table view that is contained into a view, this view has a width constraint and the height of the view will be dictated by the content height of the table view. However, I am unable to get this to work.

My attempt:
I create a view with a `leading`, `top` and `width` `constraint`. Then I insert a table view inside this view, this table view will have a leading, top, bottom and trailing constraint to the view (it's `superview`). I also set the row height and the estimate. When running the code, `numberOfRowsInSection` gets called but `cellForRowAt` does not, my guess is because the height didn't solve properly and the table has a height of 0. How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Add some code to your question to make it easier for people to understand what you are explaining in words. And yes, your cellForRow wont get called if you have return 0 in the delegate methods. You want to return an UIView height based on the UITableView content height, but you have to call the UITableView before you set the UIView height. This is the chicken and the egg problem, you need to set a positive height for the tableview to return the cell at all. So you must calculate the height outside of your UITableView methods before calling the UITableview delegate

Answer (score 0):

luis,

`UITableView` inherits from `UIScrollView`. So You cant expect the `tableView` to provide the height for its superView. In fact its vice versa.

TableView's `frame` will be decided by the superView's frame where as the tableView's `contentSize` will be decided by the data that you have provided.

So your best bets

**Solution 1:**

1. Add a height constraint to the View (SuperView) and create a IBOutlet to it in your VC.
2. Set the height for each cell in tableView lets say as 50.
3. Once you get the data to show in tableView before calling `reloadData()` on tableView set the constant of View's height constraint as

   viewsHeightConstraint.constant = (numberOfRows) * 50;

   yourView.layoutIfNeeded()

**Solution 2:**

If you are planning to use automatic height for cell then set the height of view based on the `ContentSize` of tableView. But to do that you have to get the data first, reload the tableView with the data and once done now get the content size of TableView and set the frame of your view accordingly.